# How to migrate Realm object that hasn't been stored?

Tags: ios, swift, migration, realm

I have an object that I haven't stored anywhere (yet). Even without creating a Realm for it, the app crashes saying this object requires a migration after I've modified it.

I've tried this (in method `func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool`):

```
RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion(1, forRealmAtPath: RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath()) { (migration: RLMMigration!, oldSchemaVersion: UInt) -> Void in
    if oldSchemaVersion < 1 {
        // not needed, nothing stored...
    }
}
RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
```

**Log:**

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Migration is required for object type 'PYDRealmChange' due to the following errors:
- Property 'relativePath' is missing from latest object model.
- Property 'source' has been added to latest object model.
- Property 'target' has been added to latest object model.'
```

which is what I've found in the documentation. It didn't help and the app is still crashing. My guess is that I need the *actual* Realm to perform the migration on. So my question is - how do I migrate if there is none?

Comment: Are you sure that you're setting the schema version before the first time you access the Realm? Could you also share the exception message that you're seeing? Thanks!

Comment: I added the log. I am not sure I'm setting it *before*. I just followed the documentation that told me to put that migration code to my `AppDelegate`...

Comment: But also there is no Realm to access, I never even created a Realm for that object, I created an object, but never stored it anywhere.

Comment: Are you using storyboards, and fetching from the realm in a default property value in your root view controller? Because that would access the Realm before `application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` is called.

Comment: Yes I am using Storyboards, but no I am not accessing it there. I am accessing it in `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: What's the actual backtrace of that exception being raised?

Comment: Problem solved. I didn't know that the schema needs to be updated in all realms despite the fact that I never saved the object in them.

Comment: @segiddins I am facing the issue that you described: using storyboards, and fetching from the realm in a default property value in the view controllers (the starting VC on launch can be different VCs on a tabbar controller). Realm migration in application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:) doesn't work. Where should I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277061/swift-realm-property-has-been-added-to-latest-object-model-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So problem *solved*:

What I didn't know is the fact, that I guess that the model object is set in **all** the realms existing in the app no matter whether I have stored it in them or not. The solution was to copy/paste the code `RLMRealm.setSchemaVersion...` for all the realm objects in my app. Then it started working.